# Store signed char inside unsigned int

Tags: c, data-conversion

I have an unsigned int that actually stores a signed int, and the signed int ranges from -128 to 127.

I would like to store this value back in the unsigned int so that I can simply
apply a mask 0xFF and get the signed char.

How do I do the conversion ?

i.e.

```
unsigned int foo = -100;
foo = (char)foo;
char bar = foo & 0xFF;
assert(bar == -100);
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question.

Comment: Does this give you the result you expect or an unexpected one?

Comment: Please notice: 'char', 'signed char' and 'unsigned char' are three distinct types, where 'char' is signed or not, but distinct (use signed char and avoid bit operations)

Comment: Implicit conversion like `signed char bar = foo;` will yield the same result.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov, in C, it is implementation-defined what the result of your implicit conversion will be if the value of `foo` is outside the range of values representable by type `signed char`. Supposing the conversion does not cause an implementation-defined signal to be raised.

Comment: Is your question about C or C++?  Choose **one**.

Comment: Thanks. I am concerned about the sign bit.  because bar will later be interpreted as a signed char. by simple masking. So, I need the sign bit to be in the 8th bit of the signed int.

Comment: "I have an unsigned int that actually stores a signed int" -- Why? Why not just store it in a signed int in the first place?

Comment: Is this an [X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What is the real intent?

Comment: Let me clarify the question above.....

Answer (score 2):

The `& 0xFF` operation will produce a value in the range `0` to `255`. It's not possible to get a negative number this way. So, even if you use `& 0xFF` somewhere, you will still need to apply a conversion later to get to the range `-128` to `127`.

In your code:

```
char bar = foo & 0xFF;
```

there is an implicit conversion to `char`. This relies on *implementation-defined* behaviour but this will work on all but the most esoteric of systems.  The most common implementation definition is the inverse of the conversion that applies when converting `unsigned char` to `char`.

(Your previous line `foo = (char)foo;` should be removed).

However,

```
char bar = foo;
```

would produce exactly the same effect (again, except for on those esoteric systems).

Answer (score 1):

Since the `unsigned int foo` value does not reach the boundaries of `-128` or `127` the implicit conversion will work for this case. But if `unsigned int foo` had a bigger value you will be losing bytes at the moment when storing it in a `char` variable and will get unexpected results on your program.

Comment: C does not guarantee that this will be the case.  I'm not sure about C++, but if your answer is specific to C++ then you should say so.

Comment: To my best knowledge, there is no difference between C and C++ in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

Answering for C,

If you have an `unsigned int` whose value was set by assignment of a value of type `char` (where `char` happens to be a signed type) or of type `signed char`, where the assigned value was negative, then the stored value is the arithmetic sum of the assigned negative value and one more than `UINT_MAX`.  This will be far beyond the range of values representable by (signed) `char` on any C system I have ever encountered.  If you convert that value back to (signed) `char`, whether implicitly or via a cast, "either the result is implementation-defined, or an implementation-defined signal is raised" (C2011, 6.3.1.3/3).

Converting back to the original `char` value in a way that avoids implementation-defined behavior is a bit tricky (but relying on implementation-defined behavior may afford much easier approaches).  Certainly, masking off all but the 8 lowest-order value bits does not do the trick, as it always gives you a positive value.  Also, it assumes that `char` is 8 bits wide, which, in principle, is not guaranteed.  It does not necessarily even give you the correct bit pattern, as C permits negative integers to be represented in any of three different ways.

Here's an approach that will work on any conforming C system:

```
unsigned int foo = SOME_SIGNED_CHAR_VALUE;
signed char bar;

/* ... */

if (foo <= SCHAR_MAX) {
    /* foo's value is representable as a signed char */
    bar = foo;
} else {
    /* mask off the highest-order value bits to yield a value that fits in an int */
    int foo2 = foo & INT_MAX;

    /* reverse the conversion to unsigned int, as if unsigned int had the same
       number of value bits as int; the other bits are already accounted for */
    bar = (foo2 - INT_MAX) - 1;
}
```

That relies only on characteristics of integer representation and conversion that C itself defines.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

Casting to a smaller size may truncate the value. Casting from signed to unsigned or opposite may results wrong value (e.g. 255 -> -1).

If you have to make calculations with different data types, pick one common type, prefereably signed and long int (32-bit), and check boundaries before casting down (to smaller size).

Signed helps you detect underflows (e.g. when result gets less than 0), long int (or just simply: int, which means natural word length) suits for machines (32-bit or 64-bit), and it's big enough for most purposes.

Also try to avoid mixed types in formulas, especially when they contain division (/).